# Which IAM Policy require for EC2 to run boto3 to call aws service?

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto3

I have Ec2 running with Fullec2 accessrole and running some script which has Boto3 module and calling some aws service.

Which extra IAM permission require to run boto3 ? other than configure credential file under .aws folder.

Thanks
AN

Comment: You don't configure credentials on an EC2 instance. Use EC2 instance profiles and assign whichever access rights your script requires to its associated role.

Answer (score 0):

boto3 is a Python library for making API calls to AWS. It is the **AWS Python SDK**.

Any API calls made to AWS must be made using **AWS credentials**. These credentials are associated with an **IAM (Identity and Access Management) User**. The User must be **assigned the necessary permissions** to allow them to make the call.

For example, if you wish to make an API call to create an Amazon SQS queue, the call must be made using credentials from an IAM User that has permission to call `CreateQueue()`.